# Why can't I initialize a two dimensional array with a pointer to a pointer to an int?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

Consider this code:

```
int ar[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int *ar2 = ar;
```

This code compiles. I know that `ar` decays into a pointer to an int and it makes sense that I can initialize `ar2` with `ar`.

I want to similarly initialize a two dimensional array but this code doesn't compile:

```
int ar3[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
int **ar4 = ar3;
```

Why?

Comment: You may do `int (*ar4)[2] = ar3;`.

Comment: `ar3` has a contiguous `int`. With `int**`, you have a contiguous `int*`, but no contiguous `int`.

Comment: I don't see why this is important. For instance I can have `int **x = &y;` if y is a pointer to an int and there is contiguous `int*` and this compiles.

Comment: I understand `int (*ar4)[2] = ar3;` but it seems it's necessary to specify the size (`2`). Why? In my first example with one dimensional array I didn't specify size at all.

Comment: An array is not a pointer. An array of arrays is not a pointer to pointer.